# AutoFixture - adding a cusomization so all dictionary keys are created using the object id

Tags: c#, mongodb, unit-testing, .net-core, autofixture

I'm not sure if this is possible but i thought it was worth asking.

We have a number of objects that have a hierarchy of other sub objects. Instead of using a series of IEnumerable collections we use dictionaries so that when the data is queried in MongoDb it's easy/fast to traverse the hierarchy. For example:

In the main model we have something like:

```
public Dictionary<string, TopLevelGroup> TopGroups { get; set; }
```

Then in TopLevelGroup we have something like:

```
public Dictionary<string, SecondLevelGroup> SecondLevelGroups { get; set; }
```

The key has to be a string so that it can be stored in Mongo as a ReferencedDictionary (I think that's right) and the data can be accessed simply by doing:

```
TopLevelGroup[keyA].SecondLevelGroup[keyB].Property
```

All of the keys are the id property of the object (there is a generic IDocument interface for them too which requires all documents have an Id...of course).

So what I want to do in AutoFixture is make it so all auto-generated dictionaries use the object's Id as the key (and not a randomly generated string).

I suspect this is a bit crazy and unsupported but I wanted to ask just incase as I don't know AutoFixture too well at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not at all crazy, and it *is* supported.

That scenario is what the [Customize](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2009/09/22/CustomizingAType'sBuilderWithAutoFixture/) method is useful for.

With that method you customize how the object is created.

You could maybe do this:

```cs
fixture.Customize<TopLevelGroup>(
    c => c.With(
        propertyPicker: x => x.SecondLevelGroups, 
        valueFactory: (IEnumerable<SecondLevelGroup> input) => input.ToDictionary(y => y.Id)));

fixture.Customize<MainModel>(
    c => c.With(
        propertyPicker: x => x.TopGroups, 
        valueFactory: (IEnumerable<TopLevelGroup> input) => input.ToDictionary(y => y.Id)));
```

The `With` method is used to specify a value for a property. The first argument is the propertypicker, e.g. `x => x.SecondLevelGroups`

The second argument is either a value, or a valuefactory. The valuefactory can take an input, which autofixture will populate. For example an `IEnumerable<SecondLevelGroup>` which we then can convert to a dictionary with the key that we want.

Comment: Perfect and so simple now I can see it!